# IP Address translation from external to internal

Tags: ip-address

I want to know how to translate an external IP Address to an internal IP Address. For example, how do I translate my external IP, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to an internal IP, such as my iDevice at 192.168.1.143. Any connection?

Answer (score 3):

I think I'm answering the right question.. it seems a bit unclear.

You can't. 123.456.789.101, your external IP address, is usually a router or something that uses a static IP address provided by your ISP, or the router is given an address out of a range (DHCP). The 192.168.1.X IP address is an address assigned to an internal device using either DHCP (next available address in the range) or static IP - the IP is assigned to the MAC address of the client. There is no correlation that can be mapped out.